# Parameter serialization — specify namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

I have a WCF server which has a call having 2 parameters, but which require a different namespace for each parameter. I can't seem to specify the namespace for the parameters.

So the call which is sent to the server (which I cannot adapt):

```
<ns1:myWCFCall
  xmlns:ns1="testNameSpace1"
  >
  <ns1:firstParam>
     <ns1:a></ns1:a>
     <ns1:b></ns1:b>
  </ns1:firstParam>
  <ns2:secondParam
    xmlns:ns2="testNameSpace2">
     <ns2:a></ns2:a>
     <ns2:a></ns2:a>
  </ns2:secondParam>
</ns1:myWCFCall>
```

I created a interface + implementation. I need to use XMLSerialization due to some other limitations of the standard serializer.
Specifying XMLElement on parameter level (including the namespace) doesn't seem to work at all.

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "testNameSpace1")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        myResponseObject myWCFCall(
            [XmlElement(Namespace = "testNameSpace1")] myObject firstParam, 
            [XmlElement(Namespace = "testNameSpace2")] myOtherObject secondParam);
    }

//Implementation
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public myResponseObject myWCFCall(
            [XmlElement(Namespace = "testNameSpace1")] myObject firstParam, 
            [XmlElement(Namespace = "testNameSpace2")] myOtherObject secondParam)
        {
            return new myResponseObject();
        }
     }

//Sample classes
    [Serializable]
    public class myObject
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string a;
        [XmlElement]
        public string b;
    }

//tried putting this in another C# namespace, no difference in the results.
    [Serializable]
    public class myOtherObject
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string a;
        [XmlElement]
        public string b;
    }
```

Adding     [XmlRoot(Namespace = "testNameSpace2")] doesn't work for the first level. Only for sub-sequent levels (a, b)

So I keep getting the wrong result when I check the WSDL... (ns1:secondParam instead of ns2:secondParam):

```
<ns1:myWCFCall
  xmlns:ns1="testNameSpace1"
  >
  <ns1:firstParam>
     <ns1:a></ns1:a>
     <ns1:b></ns1:b>
  </ns1:firstParam>
  <ns1:secondParam
    xmlns:ns2="testNameSpace2">
     <ns2:a></ns2:a>
     <ns2:a></ns2:a>
  </ns1:secondParam>
</ns1:myWCFCall>
```

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think out is to use MessageContract, which could control the namespace of parameter at the root level.
XmlRoot for some reason couldn't change the root element of your parameter , please refer to the link below

[Why does the XmlRoot attribute gets ignored in WCF and how to overcome this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013689/why-does-the-xmlroot-attribute-gets-ignored-in-wcf-and-how-to-overcome-this)

But in your case, you have two parameters, but messagecontract could only has one parameter. So I suggest you could use the contract as follows.

```
public class TheFirst
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string AOfTheFirst { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string BOfTheFirst { get; set; }

}

public class TheSecond
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string AOfTheFirst { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string BOfTheFirst { get; set; }

}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]  //IsWrapped= "false" removes the OuterClasselement in the request element
public class OuterClass{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace ="www.thefirst.com",Name ="aliasForFirst")]
    public TheFirst TheFirst { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace ="www.thesecond.com",Name ="aliasForSecond")]
    public TheSecond TheSecond { get; set; }




}
```

MyContract.

```
  [ServiceContract]

public interface IXmlSerService
{
    [OperationContract]

    OuterClass wcfCll(OuterClass outerClass);
}
```

MyService

```
 public  class XmlSerService:IXmlSerService
{



    public OuterClass wcfCll(OuterClass outerClass)
    {

        return new OuterClass { TheFirst = new TheFirst { AOfTheFirst = "a", BOfTheFirst = "b" },TheSecond = new TheSecond { AOfTheFirst = "a", BOfTheFirst = "b" } };
    }


}
```

The result.
  [image]

Comment: Hi, thnx for the reply. MessageContract seems to be indeed the only sollution.